# Edge with threshold bar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, edge-detection, trackbar

I am currently creating a program which manipulates and changes pixel values within black and white images. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

So far i have created edge detection using roberts gradient, 
Firstly i created this without a track bar for changing the level of the threshold.

When i added in the track bar to change the threshold value the original image would disappear off screen. the idea was to have both the original image and the processed image side by side.

Comment: Have you determined what block of code is causing the image to disappear.  It sounds like you need to use a debugger to determine that before you come here asking for help.

Comment: I have debugged it numerous times, there are no errors, from a process of elimination the only area i can see causing a problem is `private void thresholdBar1_Scroll(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        thresholdValueBox.Visible = true;

        string thresholdBarVal = Convert.ToString(thresholdBar1.Value);
        thresholdValueBox.Text = thresholdBarVal;

    }
`

Comment: Anything you draw with CreateGraphics() will disappear when the form repaints itself.  Use the Paint event instead.  Or use the PictureBox control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only update Form1_Paint method. You are never drawing proc_image in it. Any redraw will eliminate it.

```
    public void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (original_image != null)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 50, original_image.Width, original_image.Height);
            g.DrawImage(original_image, r);


        }
        if(proc_image != null)
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(535, 50, original_image.Width, original_image.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(proc_image, r);
        }
    }
```